# A panel of IR LED lights

Tags: led, resistors

I am trying to build a panel of IR LED lights  (5mm IR 940nm, forward voltage: 1.2V.)

Does each LED need a resistor or will one do for all of them?

Comment: There's manufacturing tolerances between LED's. If you place them in parallel with a single resistor then the LED's with the lowest Vf will carry much more current then the others. You can limit the current trough a series string of LED's with a single resistor tough.

Comment: It depends how are you going to connect them, and which supply voltage you are going to use, and how much current you want per LED. Add these in your question so it will become answerable.

Comment: If you're using many LEDs then the most common way to power them is multiple series strings in parallel. For example: 100 LEDs => 10 in series (so the string will need more than 12 V with your 1.2 V LEDs) with **one** resistor. Then connect 10 of these strings in parallel. So in total you will only need 10 resistors.

Comment: It depends on how you're making the current that flows in the LEDs and how the LEDs are connected together. if you're considering connecting asl the LEDs in parallel there;s almost certainly a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you are designing the circuit keep in mind: LEDs are driven by current, not voltage. Drop voltage gives you information to calculate the current restriction resistor. If the LEDs are connected in series, then the same current goes through them all and only one resistor is needed. If your connection is series-parallel combination, then you will need one resistor for each series string.